# How to convert HTML tags (eg: &lt;) into their correct tags (eg: <) in contentEditable?

Tags: html, contenteditable

How can I convert tags in a ContentEditable div so users can write in to the div and once done they can click a button and the code will be displayed

Eg: A user enters: `<li>lol</li>` it outputs `&lt;li&gt;lol&lt;/li&gt;` can I make it so it outputs the correct HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you use .text() to retrieve the contents of your div, you keep the html markup.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pzFEa

```
(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    var value = $('div').text();
    alert(value);
  });
})();
```

Or do you mean that you get HTML entities server-side? If so, please clarify.

At any rate, I recommend you not to let your users type HTML. Instead, let them use [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Comment: Thank you, But do you know how to still include tags? And make the tags not be in code (&#21;)

Comment: As I said, if you retrieve user input using .text() you keep the tags. Or do you mean using markdown? In that case, you convert that markdown to safe html in your server.